# Performant Mongo Query to get X users with specific criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo record that looks like this
and assume `$$NOW` is `2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00`

```
[
  {
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 1
  },
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 2
  },
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 3
  },
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-27T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-01T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 4
  },
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-00T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-01T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 5
  },
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-01T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-01T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 6
  },
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2022-01-01T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2022-01-01T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 7
  }
]
```

I want to get maximum 3(or any number) results from the above data, with following priority

1. randomly selected Users who signed up < 24 hrs ago, maximum of 2 records
2. randomly select remaining(3-users returned from condition 1) Users who logged in within the past 7 days and signed up >24 hours ago
3. randomly select remaining(3-users returned from condition 1+ 4) Users who logged in within the past 8 to 15 days
4. Any other random user(first 3 conditions still dint return 3 results)

condition 3 & 4 should only return data(or even run?) if condition 1 & 2 hasn't returned 3 records yet.

one possible expected result

```
[
  {
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 1
  }, // signed up < 24hrs
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 3
  }, // signed up < 24hrs
  {
    "loggedInAt": new Date("2023-01-27T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    "signedUpAt": new Date("2023-01-01T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
    id: 4
  } // logged in last 7 days & signed up > 24 hrs ago
]
```

I tried below query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "randSortKey": {
        "$rand": {}
      },
      signedUpHrs: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: "$signedUpAt",
          endDate: new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
          unit: "hour"
        }
      },
      loggedInDaysAgo: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: "$loggedInAt",
          endDate: new Date("2023-01-29T00:30:48.370+00:00"),
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      partition: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $lte: [
                  "$signedUpHrs",
                  24
                ]
              },
              then: -1
            },
            {
              case: {
                $lte: [
                  "$loggedInDaysAgo",
                  7
                ]
              },
              then: 1
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      "$loggedInDaysAgo",
                      15
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                
              },
              then: 2
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $lte: [
                      "$loggedInDaysAgo",
                      30
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                
              },
              then: 3
            },
            
          ],
          default: 4
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$partition",
      "sortBy": {
        "randSortKey": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        },
        total: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $ne: [
              "$partition",
              -1
            ]
          },
          {
            $and: [
              {
                partition: -1
              },
              {
                $lte: [
                  "$rank",
                  2
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 4
  }
])
```

It gives me results.
but my question is, is there a performant way? would this query still be good if i have millions of rows? or this is the best possible way to achieve this?

mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/HhV_Wm0vfNf

Comment: There's a lot of requirements. What have you tried so far? What is the specific error you encountered?

Comment: @ray I have modified problem state to reduce the scope, also added a query, can you check now

Comment: It's much better now so upvoted :) Your current attempt is also pretty decent and robust and I do not expect many performance caveats. [Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vxHBC3s5YWT) is another version that relies on `$unionsWith` and premature `$limit`, but I doubt that it will be much more performant than your version as yours are quite good already.